# Interpolating ASCII with utf8 gives error in open()

Tags: string, perl, utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization

As stated in the title, the problem seems to be that I have one string read from an ASCII file, and another that is utf8; when I use interpolation to form a string, and then pass that string to open(), it seems to get munged, and I get an error. Here is a minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use open ":encoding(utf8)";
use strict;

open (FILE,"<u");
my $p = <FILE>;
$p =~ s/\s+$//;
close FILE;

print "p=",$p,"\n";
if ($p eq "cat") {print "yes\n"} else {"no\n"}
my $file = "påminnelser"; # note the circle over the "a"

my $x = "$p <$file |";
print "x=$x\n";
open (FILE, $x);
close FILE;
```

It seems to make a difference that the string $p is read from the external file u, which looks like this:

```
cat
```

My code is utf8, while file u is ASCII, according to the 'file' utility:

```
---- rintintin a $ file u
u: ASCII text
---- rintintin a $ file bug.pl
bug.pl: Perl script, UTF-8 Unicode text executable
```

The result looks like this:

```
---- rintintin a $ ./bug.pl 
p=cat
yes
x=cat <påminnelser |
sh: 1: cannot open pÃ¥minnelser: No such file
```

The filename has been munged somewhere inside the call to open(). Although $p eq "cat" is true, if I simply set $p="cat" in the code rather than reading it from the file, the error goes away. I would guess that this is because my source code file is utf8.

Can anyone explain what is happening here and how to fix it?

---

[EDIT] As described in my comment on Dmitri Chubarov's answer, it turns out that my minimal example actually didn't correctly represent the bug in my original program. This question describes the actual bug: [Should perl's File::Glob always be post-filtered through utf8::decode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436275/should-perls-fileglob-always-be-post-filtered-through-utf8decode)

Comment: What's the output of `use Data::Dumper; for (glob('*minnelser')) { local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($_)); }`?

Comment: @ikegami: $VAR1 = "p\303\245minnelser"; Sorry, but I don't know how to interpret this. Did you ask because you wanted to know what it would output on my system, or because you thought it would help me to understand what was going on?

Comment: Letter “å”, which is what causes the problem in the example case, is not an ASCII character, so the title of the question is misleading. Treating ASCII data as UTF-8 does not cause problems, due to the way UTF-8 has been designed (characters in the ASCII range are represented as single bytes, identitical to their ASCII codes, i.e. any ASCII data is trivially UTF-8 data, too).

Comment: Don't use non-ASCII in file names. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436275/should-perls-fileglob-always-be-post-filtered-through-utf8decode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add

```
 use utf8;
```

pragma to your script in order for the Perl source text be interpreted as UTF8.

By default Perl source is interpreted as a stream of bytes, therefore the

```
 my $file = "påminnelser"
```

is turned into a string of bytes that is interpreted according to the default encoding.

Comment: +1 because this is helpful, but actually it doesn't solve my problem. My original program had a "use utf8" in it, and in the process of whacking it down to a minimal example I eliminated it without eliminating the error. But you're absolutely right that the minimal example above is fixed by adding "use utf8". So it appears that my minimal example is exhibiting a similar problem, but a slightly different one. In perl code, is there a way to inspect a string and find out what encoding it's in? Maybe that would help me to track down the bug in its original form.

Comment: Interesting. The problem could be related to the scope of the pragma directive. Perhaps the `utf8::is_utf8($string)` function provided in the `utf8::` package would help to determine what type of string you are seeing.

Comment: Sorry, please ignore the comment above. I think I have enough to work with here.