# Should perl's File::Glob always be post-filtered through utf8::decode?

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, internationalization

The output of the following minimal example shows that (on my linux machine) File::Glob seems to have the unexpected side-effect of converting a utf8 string to non-utf8:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use utf8;

use strict;

my $x = "påminnelser";
my $y = glob $x;

print "x=",utf8::is_utf8($x),"=\n";
print "y=",utf8::is_utf8($y),"=\n";
```

This is causing wrong behavior in my program. On linux, it looks like I can fix it by applying utf8::decode() after File::Glob. Is this the right way to fix this? Is this a bug in File::Glob? Will my fix produce correct results on other systems such as Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encoding handling of functions dealing with file names is currently on perl's todo list: [Unicode in Filenames](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/Porting/todo.pod). Problem is that some popular operating systems (i.e. Linux) don't have support for file name encoding (other than using the current locale settings, but this is broken by design), so getting a portable solution in Perl is not that easy.

My advice is to avoid non-ASCII file names at all.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information, +1. But this doesn't answer my question, which was whether my workaround was correct and/or advisable. I don't want to arbitrarily tell my users that they can't have non-ASCII filenames.

Comment: It's only advisable if all your users are using utf8 as the encoding for file names. If you have users who have, say, no_NO.ISO8859-1 as their locale and create file names according to this locale, then it won't work. In this case you have start to guess, maybe using `Encode::Guess` or similar modules.

Comment: I see. So I think the answer to my question is that my proposed workaround is a bad idea and is likely to be broken for some users. +1